# Android Error when using Multiple Views

Tags: android, view

I have created an application in the past that switched from the first screen to the next when a button was clicked. I am trying to modify a new application to do similar, but instead have two screens to choose from. On the main screen are two radio buttons, and I want the corresponding view to appear depending on the user's selection. When I attempt to do this, though, no error appears on the program, but an error does popup when I try to run it. There is no error reported in the console nor the log. It only occurs after introducing my new xml file. My eventual goal is to create an application like MadLibs.

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="@string/cat" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/categoryTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/categoryTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/bkRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/bekind" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/oldmcRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/oldmc" />


</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/chooseButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/choose"
    android:onClick="buttonclick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

bekindwords.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nounKindTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/noun" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nounKindEditText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nounpKindTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/nounp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nounpKindEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nounKindTextView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/noun" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nounKindEditText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/placeKindTextView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/place" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/placeKindEditText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/adjKindTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/adj" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/@+id/adjKindEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nounKindTextView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/noun" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nounKindEditText3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/enterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttonclick2"
    android:text="@string/ent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main.java:

```
package com.deitel.adlibs;

import com.deitel.adlibs.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class Main extends Activity {
//Global variable
        double bk;
        private Button choose;  // creates a button 

            @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            choose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooseButton);

            //Start with first screen
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

      //buttonclick for form 1
        public void buttonclick(View view){

            RadioButton bk = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.bkRadio);

             if(bk.isChecked())
            {
                //switch views to screen 2
                   setContentView(R.layout.bekindwords);  
            }

            }
             }
```

Comment: What does the error that pops up say? If your app is force closing there will be something in the log cat indicating why.

Comment: "Your project contains error(s) please fix them before running your application." It pops up instantly.

Comment: That is a compile error, so something is wrong with either your java code or your xml that is causing it not to compile. Inside of your package explorer do any of your files have a red 'X' by them? If so that is the file with the error. If not try cleaning your project, sometimes "phantom" errors happen that can be fixed only by cleaning the project.

Comment: I have cleaned it and there are no red indicators of an error. I think it has to do with trying to link to the other xml file... but I am not certain. My Java should link to it... I have been trying to research the problem, but finding nothing.

Comment: I guess you can not have multiple views for same activity. Either you can use viewflipper or have 2 activities.

Comment: You can refer http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Android-Multiple-Views-/68111 this tutorial.

Comment: I have done two views before... it's odd. All right, I'll look at the tutorial. thanks!

Comment: The tutorial I've seen previously. It's a good tutorial,but not what I was looking for.